# Send email after checked or unchecked " approved" in ActiveAdmin to notify the user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

i want to notify a user when he's approved or not.

in **admin/user.rb** i have

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do

  permit_params :email, :name, :firstname, :mailsent, :email_confirmed, 
 :adminuser, :approved

 index do
  column :email
  column :name
  column :firstname
  column :mailsent
  column :email_confirmed
  column :adminuser
  column :approved
 actions
 end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the update method. Ensure you only send the email if there were no errors that prevented update and (of course) only if the approved column changes.

```
controller do
  def update
    @approved = User.find(params[:id]).try(:approved)
    super
    if @user.valid? && @user.approved != @approved
      # send email here
    end
  end
end
```